# Checking if one ajax call is in progress that I don't fire another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript function like this :

```
addGas = function(options){
    var working = false;

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
      if (settings.url == '/add_gas') {
        working = true;        
      }
    });

    if(working) {
      return;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: options.url,
      data: options,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $(".btn").addClass("added").text(" Added gas ").prepend("<i></i>");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

      }
    });
  }
```

So the way I test this is that I put 10 seconds sleep in my controller, and try to click the button again, and it makes a post request who is waiting, because my server can server one request at a time.

But I wanted not to send a post request if one is already running, alternatively alert a message if the request is already running.

How can I do that?

Comment: Firstly, why are you setting `ajaxSend` handler inside addGas function?

Comment: I dont I guess I missunderstood the article I found online.Should I set it elsewhere?

Comment: This isn't really a Rails or Ruby question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a singleton handling its own state, this way you dont pollute the rest of the code with unused variables

```
gasHandlerBuilder = function(){
  var ajaxInProgress = false;
  return { 
    add_gas: function(options){
      if(ajaxInProgress){ return; };
      ajaxInProgress = true;
      $.ajax({
        url: options.url,
        data: options,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
          ajaxInProgress = false;
          $(".btn").addClass("added").text(" Added gas ").prepend("<i></i>");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          ajaxInProgress = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

var gasHandler = gasHandlerBuilder();
gasHandler.add_gas(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some flag, something like this :

```
var recieved = false;
$.ajax({
    url: "http://first.call/",
})
.done(function( data ) {
    // Do something with that data and enable the flag
    recieved = true;
});

addGas = function(options){
    var working = false;

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
        if (settings.url == '/add_gas') {
            working = true;        
        }
    });

    if(!recieved) {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: options.url,
        data: options,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $(".btn").addClass("added").text(" Added gas ").prepend("<i></i>");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        }
    });
}
```